# mysql query is not optimized

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have tried to optimize this query but can't do it due to specific business requirements.

Tables:

- `b2`: about 2mil records, store business records
- `business_reviews`: small table, store reviews for businesses (each biz can have multiple reviews)
- `business_feature_item`: small table, store features for businesses (each biz can have multiple features

specific business requirements for the result:

- show business records
- show associated reviews for business as well
- allow to search for features too
- sort by b2.starbiz and the score (generated by MATCH AGAINST)

My current query use temp table, union all and sorting so it doesn't work very well when the result is large. Is there a way to re-write this query to make it work more efficient?

```
SELECT temp.* FROM 

(SELECT DISTINCT b.business_id, b.description AS `extra`, '1' AS `type`, 0 as score 

FROM b2 as b 

LEFT JOIN business_feature_item AS i ON b.business_id = i.business_id 

WHERE ((b.cat_id = '93' OR b.cat_id2 = '93' OR b.cat_id3 = '93')) 

AND b.city_id = '152262' 

AND `approved`=1 

UNION ALL SELECT b.business_id, review_desc AS `extra`, '2' AS `type`, ((MATCH         `review_desc` AGAINST ('"restaurants"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 4) + (MATCH `review_desc` AGAINST ('restaurants' IN BOOLEAN MODE) )) AS score 

FROM b2 AS b, business_reviews AS r 

WHERE b.business_id =r.business_id 

AND b.city_id = '152262' 

AND ( MATCH `review_desc` AGAINST ('"restaurants"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 

OR MATCH `review_desc` AGAINST ('restaurants' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) 

AS temp 

GROUP BY temp.business_id 

ORDER BY starbiz DESC, score DESC
```

Comment: Please try to format the question so that it is readable. Thanks.

Comment: Could you possibly simplify the select statement?

Comment: I have cut down the fields in select

Comment: Is the enter key not working for you? Also ditch some of the field names after `DISTINCY`. Makes life a little easier when you can see the wood from the trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `OR` clause will cause MySQL to not use any indexes, but instead do full table scans.

Try rewriting the query to use `UNION ALL`s instead of `OR`s:

```
SELECT temp.* FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        b.business_id, 
        b.description AS `extra`,
        '1' AS `type`,
        0 as score 
    FROM 
        b2 as b 
    LEFT JOIN 
        business_feature_item AS i ON b.business_id = i.business_id 
    WHERE 
        b.cat_id = '93'
        AND b.city_id = '152262' 
        AND `approved`=1 
UNION ALL 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        b.business_id, 
        b.description AS `extra`,
        '1' AS `type`,
        0 as score 
    FROM 
        b2 as b 
    LEFT JOIN 
        business_feature_item AS i ON b.business_id = i.business_id 
    WHERE 
        b.cat_id2 = '93'
        AND b.city_id = '152262' 
        AND `approved`=1 
UNION ALL 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        b.business_id, 
        b.description AS `extra`,
        '1' AS `type`,
        0 as score 
    FROM 
        b2 as b 
    LEFT JOIN 
        business_feature_item AS i ON b.business_id = i.business_id 
    WHERE 
        b.cat_id3 = '93'
        AND b.city_id = '152262' 
        AND `approved`=1 
UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        b.business_id,
        review_desc AS `extra`,
        '2' AS `type`,
        MATCH `review_desc` AGAINST ('"restaurants"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 4 AS score
    FROM 
        b2 AS b,
        business_reviews AS r 
    WHERE 
        b.business_id =r.business_id 
        AND b.city_id = '152262' 
        AND MATCH `review_desc` AGAINST ('"restaurants"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        b.business_id,
        review_desc AS `extra`,
        '2' AS `type`,
        MATCH `review_desc` AGAINST ('restaurants' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
    FROM 
        b2 AS b,
        business_reviews AS r 
    WHERE 
        b.business_id =r.business_id 
        AND b.city_id = '152262' 
        AND MATCH `review_desc` AGAINST ('restaurants' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) 
AS temp 
GROUP BY temp.business_id 
ORDER BY starbiz DESC, score DESC
```

Comment: thanks Ross. Getting error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM b2 AS b, business_reviews AS r WHERE b.busin' at line 50

Comment: actually found extra ) on line 49. changed that and added b.starbiz to select clauses. I'm testing to see if the results are as expected.

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 436 total, Query took 0.2031 sec), working faster than before but still slow

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on the fields you are querying on. For example: `ALTER TABLE b2 ADD INDEX ix_city_cat_approved ON (city_id, cat_id, approved);
ALTER TABLE b2 ADD INDEX ix_business_city ON (business_id, city_id);
ALTER TABLE business_reviews ADD INDEX ix_business ON (business_id);
`